# Reorganize directory structure with Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I have a project with directory structure

```
Foo/
    .hg
    Bar1/
        ...
    Bar2/
        ...
    Zope/
        ...
```

I want to change this to

```
Foo/
    .hg
    Source/
        Bar1/
            ...
        Bar2/
            ...
    Zope/
        ...
```

What is the easiest way? (There are too many files to move them one-by-one. And there are several files with identical content, so if I just move the files and ask Mercurial to figure things out afterwards, then things get a little messy.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mercurial has a special command to move stuff: `hg mv`
When you move your folders like this, it knows in the history that `Foo/Source/Bar/SomeFile` was previously `Foo/Bar/SomeFile`.
So when you look at the history of `Foo/Source/Bar/SomeFile` now, you also see the changes that were made when the file was still `Foo/Bar/SomeFile`.

Here's an example how to move the `Bar1` folder into the `Source` folder and commit:

```
hg mv Bar1 Source
hg commit -m "moved to Source folder"
```

Answer (score 0):

Drag the 2 Bar folders into the new Source folder and commit.

Comment: There are a bunch of files with identical content, such as StdAfx.cpp files. Then Mercurial does not get unique matches, and things get messy.